# Underscores in dataframe columns. Is this the expected behaviour?

Tags: r

If I do

```
x_y<-sample(1:10,20,replace=TRUE)
df<-data.frame(x_y)
df$x_y
```

I get

```
[1]  8  3  5  1 10  7  6  4  4  9  1  6  3  8  8  8  7  4  7  5
```

If I do

```
'x' %in% colnames(df)
```

I get `FALSE`.

However, if I do

```
df$x
```

I get

```
[1]  8  3  5  1 10  7  6  4  4  9  1  6  3  8  8  8  7  4  7  5
```

So: `x` is not a column but returns the same values as `x_y`. My question is: Is this the expected behaviour or I am doing something wrong? Perhaps underscores are not recommended in column names?

UPDATE: I just realised that this is valid not only for underscores. If I have a column called `qwerty` and I ask for the column `qwer`, I also get the data from `qwerty`. It seems I am using partial matching and I didn't know it.

Comment: Yes, it is a "feature" of partial matching when using `$`. You can also do the same with `x1<-sample(1:10,20,replace=TRUE)`. Check `?Extract`.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know `$` is "partial matching", thanks! I'll check now the `?Extract`. How could I call the "exact matching"?

Comment: Exact matching with `[[`: `df[['x']]`

Comment: Ok, thank you both. I didn't know that. I was actually working on a code written by somebody else and he was using partial matching as if it were exact matching, and I thought this was the usual way to get column values. Now I see my question didn't make sense. I'll delete it. Thank you so much!